# mysql: get all tables in database that have a column called xyz

Tags: mysql

mysql: get all tables in database that have a column called xyz

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both SQL Server and MySql have the Information_Schema.Columns table:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/columns-table.html

```
select c.table_name from 
information_schema.columns c 
where c.column_name = 'xyz'
```

Comment: Yes, MySQL has that too and the Statement works fine, but why are you using "like" without any wildcard instead of "=" ?

Comment: Copy/pasted it from a quick test on our DB here where i was using a wildcard, fixed now - ta! :)